# sum the value with rollup mysql

Tags: mysql

i'm currently working on mysql code right now, and i'm stumbled on minor problem, so the thing is i wanna sum the value on mysql query, i already use with rollup but the output is not what i wanted to be, here's my query

```
select mkgroupa, next_mkgroup, mkgroup_name, count_group from (
select data_tarikan_whatsapp.mkgroup mkgroupa,
data_tarikan_whatsapp.exp_polis exp_date,
CASE 
  WHEN data_tarikan_whatsapp.mkgroup in('MKGROUP7', 'MKGROUP4', 'MKGROUP3A', 'MKGROUP8')
  THEN 'MKGROUP7'
  WHEN data_tarikan_whatsapp.mkgroup in('MKGROUP5', 'MK-CSSEC') 
  THEN 'LAIN-LAIN' 
  ELSE data_tarikan_whatsapp.mkgroup
END next_mkgroup,
mkgroup_master.mkgroup_desc mkgroup_name,
    (select count(id) from data_tarikan_whatsapp
    where mkgroup = mkgroupa
    and exp_polis between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-31'
    limit 1
    ) count_group
from data_tarikan_whatsapp, mkgroup_master
where exp_polis between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-31'
and data_tarikan_whatsapp.mkgroup = mkgroup_master.mkgroup_code 
group by mkgroupa
)a
```

and here's the ouput

| mkgroupa | next_mkgroup | mkgroup_name | count_group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MKGROUP3A | MKGROUP7 | MKGROUP3A | 201 |
| MKGROUP4 | MKGROUP7 | MKGROUP4 | 1019 |
| MKGROUP5 | LAIN-LAIN | MKGROUP5 | 5 |
| MKGROUP8 | MKGROUP7 | MKGROUP8 | 315 |
| 18-MKG01 | 18-MKG01 | YOGYAKARTA | 20 |

but the output that i wanted to be is sum the mkgroup7 to be 1 line and sum the number like this:

| mkgroupa | next_mkgroup | mkgroup_name | count_group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MKGROUP4 | MKGROUP7 | MKGROUP4 | 1535 |
| MKGROUP5 | LAIN-LAIN | MKGROUP5 | 5 |
| 18-MKG01 | 18-MKG01 | YOGYAKARTA | 20 |

that would be great if you help me guys, thankyou.

Comment: I do NOT see `GROUP BY .. WITH ROLLUP` in your query.

Comment: Why `MKGROUP4` for `next_mkgroup=MKGROUP7` is selected and another 2 values are ignored? is it minimal value? If so then add `GROUP BY next_mkgroup` to outer query and MIN()/SUM() to its output list.

Comment: @Akina yes in this query im not using group by with rollup because of weird output, that's why i wanted to know how to use group by with rollup properly

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT MIN(mkgroupa) mkgroupa, 
       next_mkgroup, 
       MIN(mkgroup_name) mkgroup_name, 
       SUM(count_group) count_group 
FROM ( {your subquery text} ) a
GROUP BY next_mkgroup;
```

PS. Of course, the values of `mkgroupa` and `mkgroup_name` selected by MIN() in the output may belong to different rows. If you need them to belong to the same row then use additional ordering expression in subquery and CASE in MIN() argument (or window function FIRST_VALUE) of the outer query.

Comment: This works like charming after few edits, thankyou so much, may you always have a great life everyday